# Summing over Partitions

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, partitions

Imagine I have a list of integers $l=\{l_1,l_2,...,l_{50}\}$, say, for example

```
l = RandomInteger[10, 50]
```

and I want to find how many ways there are of summing numbers from that list such that the sum is a given number $K$. In other words, I'm looking for all the possible combinations of coefficients $\{x_1,...,x_{50}\}$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{50} x_i l_i=K
$$
where $x_i\in\{0,1\}$. I suppose this could be a very demanding calculation, but I wonder if there is a good or efficient way of finding these combinations and listing them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One idea is to use [`BooleanCountingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanCountingFunction) and [`SatisfiabilityInstances`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityInstances). First, a helper function that creates a list of `n` variables and a boolean expression asserting that all or none of the variables are true (in other words, each member `k` of your list is represented by `k` boolean variables):

```
g[n_] := With[{v = Table[Unique[], n]},
    {v, BooleanCountingFunction[{{0, n}}, n] @@ v}
]
```

This helper function is mapped over each element of your list. Then, a [`BooleanCountingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanCountingFunction) is created that is true when the target number of variables are true. Finally, [`SatisfiabilityInstances`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SatisfiabilityInstances) is used to find variables that satisfy the individual boolean expressions and the [`BooleanCountingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanCountingFunction). Here's some code that finds the counts and the instances:

```
counts[v_, t_] := Module[{vv=g/@v, len, var, bool, i},
    var = Flatten[vv[[All, 1]]];
    len = Length @ var;
    bool = BooleanCountingFunction[{t}, len] @@ var && And @@ vv[[All, 2]];
    SatisfiabilityCount[bool, var]
]

instances[v_, t_] := Module[{vv=g/@v, len, var, bool, i},
    var = Flatten[vv[[All, 1]]];
    len = Length @ var;
    bool = BooleanCountingFunction[{t}, len] @@ var && And @@ vv[[All, 2]];
    i = Thread[var->#]& /@ SatisfiabilityInstances[bool, var, All];
    Boole[vv[[All, 1, 1]] /. i]
]
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
l = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 50];

counts[l, 10] //AbsoluteTiming
res = instances[l, 10]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.010638, 70934}

> {28.4981, Null}

Check:

```
Tally[res . l]
```

> {{10, 70934}}

Finding the instances is unfortunately rather slow.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The functions you use are unfamiliar to me, and your example helps me understand them. Can you tell me why the result `res` always has nine 1 and the rest 0? How would you find the case with two 1, for example {1,0,0,1,0,0,...,0}?

Comment: @KennyColnago Thanks, I had a bug in the definition of `g`, and fixing this bug means that the instances code is quite a bit slower.

Comment: This seems fantastic Carl, I will take a careful look and try to implement it in my code :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[list_ /; Length[list] > 0, k_Integer?Positive] := Module[{x, var},
  var = Array[x, Length[list]];
  var /. Solve[{list.var == k, 0 <= var <= 1} // Flatten, var, Integers]]

SeedRandom[1]

list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 50]

(* {2, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 9, 7, 1, 5, 2, 9, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5, 6, \
5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 10, 6, 2, 6, 3, 4, 10, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 6, 3} *)

k = 10;

sol = f[list, k];
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
And @@ (#.list == k & /@ sol)

(* True *)
```

There are too many solutions to look at

```
Length@sol

(* 70934 *)
```

Looking at the non-zero entries of the first ten solutions along with the corresponding list elements

```
(Transpose[{list, #}] & /@ sol[[1 ;; 10]]) /. {_, 0} :> Nothing

(* {{{5, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{5, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{5, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{1, 
   1}, {6, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 1}, {6, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {5, 1}, {3, 
   1}}, {{2, 1}, {5, 1}, {3, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 1}, {5, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{2, 
   1}, {1, 1}, {5, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{10, 1}}} *)
```